# How to differentiate $F(y) = \left(\frac{1}{y^2}-(\frac{-2}{y^4})\right)\cdot\left(y+5y^{3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I tried to differentiate this function, and was able to differentiate the second portion $(y + 5y^3)$, but I could not differentiate the $\left(\frac{1}{y^2}-(\frac{-2}{y^4})\right)$ term. Now I know that to complete the differentiation I need to multiply the first term by $(15x^2+1)$, but how do I get the term to multiply by $(y+5y^3)$ and simplify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the term $\frac{1}{y^2}$ as $y^{-2}$ so $$(\frac{1}{y^2})'=(y^{-2})'=-2\times y^{-2-1}=-2\times y^{-3}$$ Now, do the same to $\frac{1}{y^4}$. Note that, I assumed $y$ is an independent variable here.

Comment: I did this and ended up with 5-(8y^-6)-(4y^-4)-(10y^-2). What did I do wrong? What is the correct way to finish this derivation?

Comment: @cuabanana: See what did frogeyedpeas do. He/she did it right. :)

Answer (score 4):

$$F(y)=((1/y^2)-(-2/y^4)(y+5y^3)=y^{-2}+2y^{-4}(y+5y^3)=y^{-2}+2y^{-3}+10y^{-1}$$
$$F'(y)=-2y^{-3}-6y^{-4}-10y^{-2}=-2y^{-2}(y^{-1}+3y^{-2}+5)$$

Comment: The expression for $F(y)$ has mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

We will use product rule:

F(y) = a(y) * b(y)

b(y) = (y + 5y^3)

b'(y) = (1 + 15y^2)

a(y) = (1/y^2 - (-2/y^4))

simplifying:

a(y) = (1/y^2 + 2/y^4)

Note: a'(y) = (-2/y^3 - 8/y^5) (just express the 1/y^k as y^(-k) and apply regular power rule)

Now we know F'(y) = a'(y)b(y) + a(y)b'(y)

Thus: F'(y) = (-2/y^3 - 8/y^5)(y + 5y^3) + (1/y^2 + 2/y^4)(1 + 15*y^2)

The rest of your work is simply putting each component with common denominators and seeing if anything reduces... That is just going to be a lot grind work... good luck!